# Скрипт для базы данных php

Tags: php

1) Есть база данных в ней есть поля id title foregin
2) в title перечислены отечественные машины и иностранные
3) иностранные машины записаны в таблице на английском языке, отечественные на русском
4) в иностранных машинах foregin должен быть 1, а в отечественных 0 
4) как мне в записи с иностранными машинами поместить foregin 1

Comment: Можете по подробней описать вашу проблему. Для чего нужен foregin?

Comment: *иностранные слова написаны на транслите ?* не русскими же буквами?

Comment: английскими буквами

Comment: foregin пишится 0 если машины иностранные 1 если отечественные

Comment: и иностранные машины записаны в базе английскими буквами

Comment: как то так  `update teblename set foreign=1 where title REGEXP "[a-z -]"`

Comment: вместо пробела и дефиса напишите символы, которые могут быть в транслитерации

Answer (score 2):

Регулярным выражением проверьте, содержаться ли латинские символы.

```
update mytable set `foregin` = 1 where `title` REGEXP '[a-z\s\-]+';
```

Comment: 1) экранировать минус, если он последний не надо. 2) mysql ищет регистронезависимо

Comment: точно регулярки можно же юзать, спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @splash58, спасибо поправил, уже не помню. Но думаю это зависит от настроек и кодировки.